# How do I transfer progress from Xbox one to Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, call-of-duty-black-ops-3

My question is opposite from everyone else's, as I am going from the Xbox one down to the 360. I have been playing black ops 3 on the Xbox one,  and wanted to play it on the 360 also.  The problem is,  none of my progress has been saved. On the Xbox one I have all my weapons customized,  specialist customized, everything how I want it. But,  on the 360 nothing is saved and I'm level one.

So how do I transfer my progress over from the Xbox one to the 360? Please help,  this is very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware there is no compatibility in that direction, only Xbox 360 to XBox one via the cloud.

You could attempt saving xbox one progress to the cloud and then accessing it from the xbox 360-id love to know if this would work but probably not

Comment: The cloud saves work both ways. You just need to give the console you last played game X on time to sync the save to the cloud. Otherwise, you'll be playing an older version of the save on the other console, and the most recent sync to the cloud is the one that wins in case of a conflict.